# SonarQube not displaying Unit Test results

Tags: java, testing, junit, sonarqube

I have JUnit test reports in in the format "TEST-*.xml" and I am trying to upload these to SonarQube using Ant. I have put in my build.xml file the following properties, where ${reports.dir} evaluates to the report directory path:

```
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports"/>
<property name="sonar.junit.reportsPath" value="${reports.dir}"/>
```

Here is the output from the Ant task (with certain information redacted):

```
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 2.1
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Ant/apache-ant-1.9.3-
bin/apache-ant-1.9.3/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "en_IE", source code encoding: "windows-1252"
(analysis is platform dependent)
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Sonar Server 3.7.3
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:00.626 INFO  - Load batch settings
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:00.689 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Administrator\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:00.689 INFO  - Install plugins
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:03.356 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:03.356 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for
jdbc:mysql://<REDACTED>:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&
characterEncoding=utf-8
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:04.916 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:09.986 INFO  - Load project settings
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:10.033 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:10.283 INFO  - -------------  Scan <REDACTED>
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:10.283 INFO  - Load module settings
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.250 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.265 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.265 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.359 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.499 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-04-05)
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.546 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-03-06, analysis of 
2014-04-05 20:09:46.0)
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.624 INFO  - Compare to previous version
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.843 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.843 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.843 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_IE
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.858 INFO  - parsing C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestResults
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 94 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:11.952 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.404 INFO  - Sensor ProfileSensor done: 452 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.404 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.420 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 16 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.420 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 31 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% since there is no
directories with classes.
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.451 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:12.794 INFO  - Execute decorators...
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.106 INFO  - Store results in database
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.184 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse <REDACTED>
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.231 INFO  - Executing post-job class 
org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.231 INFO  - Executing post-job class 
org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.293 INFO  - Executing post-job class
org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.309 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-03-08 and
2014-04-04
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.309 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-04-06
and 2014-03-08
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.309 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-04-11
and 2013-04-06
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.309 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2009-04-11
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.309 INFO  - -> Clean <REDACTED> [id=12]
[sonar:sonar] 20:53:13.325 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 21

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 17 seconds
```

I've got no idea why SonarQube is telling me that there were zero JUnit tests. As far as I can tell the Ant task was successful (so they were uploaded, right?). Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the code coverage, or just the unit test results?

Comment: Just the unit test results. The reports are already generated, I'm just uploading the results

Comment: Did you check the contents of the C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestResults folder? Does it contain the test results xml files, or is there maybe a subdirectory structure? Do the xml files look ok? Also could you run ant -v to perhaps get more logging info?

Comment: Yep the folder has the xml files and they are formatted fine. I might try an upgrade to the latest server version

Comment: You could also try a small maven setup to see whether it is the ant plugin or a server issue.

Answer (score 7):

Add a property *sonar.tests* pointing to the directory containing your tests.

The property would look like

```
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${tests.dir}"/>
```

You can find the documentation here.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: Where should I add this in a maven project?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you haven't set the "sonar.tests" property - so SonarQube did not import test classes and could not attach test results to them.

Comment: Could you clarify how to use the "sonar.tests" property? At the moment I am simply uploading test results and don't need code coverage reports (I don't actually have access to the unit tests source code).

Comment: More info and explainings: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters